# Push page on top most NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have an XF app where I have the following navigation stacks:

- NavigationPage

  - TabbedPage

    - NavigationPage (this is the root of the 1. tab)

      - ContentPage1
    - NavigationPage (this is the root of the 2. tab)

      - **ContentPage2 (currently active page)**
    - NavigationPage (this is the root of the 3. tab)

      - ContentPage3

What I want to accomplish is to navigate, with a URL, from the currently active page to a page that gets pushed onto the root NavigationPage's stack resulting in something like this:

- NavigationPage

  - TabbedPage

    - NavigationPage (this is the root of the 1. tab)

      - ContentPage1
    - NavigationPage (this is the root of the 2. tab)

      - ContentPage2
    - NavigationPage (this is the root of the 3. tab)

      - ContentPage3
  - **ContentPage3 (new active page)**

If I try to do this by navigating to **/NavigationPage/ContentPage3** the TabbedPage and all subpages are destroyed. If I instead use **/NavigationPage/TabbedPage/ContentPage3** the TabbedPage and subpages are still destroyed, but then recreated to make the URL match.

I'd like to accomplish this without destroying the existing pages.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to not to destroy existing pages is to use an Modal Page.
You can modify the Appearance of the ModalPage so that appears like a normal page.
Also, while navigating you can set the animation to false so that the Page appears directly without animation.

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing, but I'd like to avoid using modals due to the animation being different (and no I don't want to just disable animation).